How can we further process the baseband recording to get the data sent from the sender node?
Like; if in a simulation, a node records baseband signal, what and how signal gets recorded ?
Also, if we transmit baseband signal from a node, Can I record the same baseband from another node in simulation ?
In a two-node simulation, I sent data using baseband service and recorded the signal from another node. But, I could not able to extract the data sent from first node in second node interface.

In unet audio or on a real modem, you should be able to send a RxBasebandSignalReq with the baseband signal to phy and it will try to decode the signal into data and generate appropriate RxFrameNtf or BadFrameNtf.
In a simulation using HalfDuplexModem, the simulation is at a packet level and no acoustic signal is created or decoded at the physical layer. The physical layer in network simulation is an abstraction that only supports detection probability, decoding probability, etc, to allow much faster than real-time network simulations.
